# reportValidity() failure with form-associated customElement

Tags: custom-element

I have a form-associated customElement which manages its own validity and validation messages. It works as expected as a member of a form; calling `form.reportValidity()` will place the appropriate error message on the appropriate anchor element. However, calling `customElement.reportValidity()` results in the error: `An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.`

My understanding of `reportValidity()` is that we can call it on individual elements, whether it is a member of an `HTMLFormControlsCollection` or not. For example, you can call report validity on the following orphan `input`:

```js
document.querySelector("#foo").reportValidity();
```

```html
<input id="foo" value="" required>
```

So because the above works, I don't believe I'm out of line with any design principle.

My minimal repro sets up a form associted custom element by calling `attachInternals` and building a shadowDom of a single input element. A single instance of this custom element is nested within a form element. The page loads, and calls `reportValidity` on both the form and the custom element. The call on the custom element fails:

```js
class FACE extends HTMLElement {
    static get formAssociated() { return true; }
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode:"open"});
        this._internals = this.attachInternals();        
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<input id="foo" value="initial">`;
        let errorAnchor = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#foo");
        this._internals.setValidity({badInput: true}, "Some error message", errorAnchor);
    }

    reportValidity() { // expose reportValidity on the CE's surface
        return this._internals.reportValidity();
    }
}

customElements.define("fa-ce", FACE);
customElements.whenDefined("fa-ce").then(
    () => {
        // reports custom validation message
        document.querySelector("form").reportValidity();
        // "An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable."
        document.querySelector("fa-ce").reportValidity();
    }
);
```

```html
<form>
    <fa-ce></fa-ce>
</form>
```

So (most probable) I'm doing something wrong and you might could help, or this is a bug in (Chrome's) custom elements (FF hasn't implemented `attachInternals` yet), or this is as designed and what I'm trying to do can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update** There now is a Bug reported:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1139621&q=%22not%20focusable%22&can=2

This answer might no longer be valid.

---

You need to make the Form Element *inside* shadowDOM focusable
when you create the shadowDOM:

```
this.attachShadow({
        mode: "open",
        delegatesFocus: true
      });
```

Does not seem to work in a SO snippet...

working JSFiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/9uq15ndr/

.

a `delegateFocus` explanation JSFiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/n7mrkxz6

**as you said: This does not work in FireFox yet** (jan 2020)

works in Chrome, Edge, Safari (last one I did not test myself)

Another cause of the error can be a hidden required Field, which the browser can't focus on

`<input type="hidden" required />`

Comment: Your first JSFiddle doesn't work for me in Chrome 90 or 91 - I get the error "An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable." The only way I've been able to avoid the "not focusable" error is to explicitly set a tabindex on the custom element, and **not** set delegatesFocus to true. Looks like it's a bug in Blink/Chromium's implementation: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1139621&q=%22not%20focusable%22&can=2